# UITabBar selectedImageTintColor with RGB doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

When I am setting selectedImageTintColor of UITabBar this way, the code works:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
```

[image]

But when I am setting with RGB, like this

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:162/255 blue:0/250 alpha:1]];
```

Which is a bit lighter orange, [image]

The selectedImageTintColor of UITabBar becomes red

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `.0f` at the end of each `/255`:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor: 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f 
                    green:162/255.0f 
                     blue:0/250.0f 
                    alpha:1]];
```

Problem happens because `162/255` recognized as operation on int values hence when it gets automatically rounded and you receive `0` so you final color is `R:255 G:0 B:0` which is exactly what you get. Adding `.0f` tells compiler that you want to deal with floats so precision does not get lost and you obtain value with fraction.